# multiple conversion bam to bed using bedtools

Tags: shell, files, conversion, bioinformatics

I have ten .bam files (bioinformatic format) and I would like to convert it to 10 .bed files, but for this conversion I need to use special command

```
bedtools bamTobed -i (input file) > output file.bed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe this shell command helps.

```
for x in *.bam; do
    bedtools bamTobed -i "$x" >"${x%.bam}.bed"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

```
parallel --jobs <int> "bamToBed -i {} > {.}.bed" ::: *.bam
```